# render media file to html template from views.py django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to show image from views.py to jinga2 html template.
Here is code
**models.py**

```
class SkinModel(models.Model):
    pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SkinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SkinModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SkinForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            img=form.cleaned_data['pic']
            if img:
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                filename = fs.save(img.name, img)
                path = fs.url(filename)
                print(path)
                return render(request,'home.html',{'form':form,'path':path})
```

**home.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{{ path }}" ,width="500" height="400">
```

the print statement shows the path like `/media/bcc_38Mf6gh.jpg` but i dont know how to render it on html template

Comment: This section could be useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#managing-files

Comment: To display the uploaded image from the view code you have you would have to pass `img` object into the context when you do the render `render(request,'home.html',{'form':form,'img':img})` and get it in template as `{{ img.pic.url }}`.

Comment: `img.pic` is not the file stored in media folder, the file in media folder can be access via `filename`

Comment: Right, I think I was confused by the model form. Do you have `{{ path }}` variable rendered correctly in HTML? If path is correct there it would be a good idea to check if you have correct configuration to serve media files locally. You might have to add `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in your url.py. Keep in mind that it should be enabled only for the development mode and not be used on production.

Comment: actually it print out my path instead of rendering image, so i thinking i called i am not calling it properly.

Comment: it display "D:\myfolder\my_app\sub_app\media\download_gZTvUGl.jpg" like this, instead of converting it to an image

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `fs.url(filename)` and not `fs.path(filename)`?    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.url gives the desired result.

Comment: the only difference is relative vs absolute path, but i am having issue in rendering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242580/discussion-between-rootart-and-talha-anwar).

Answer (score 0):

Install Pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```

And then add .url to path:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{{ path.url }}" ,width="500" height="400">
```